# Which Windows remote desktop software can mount remote drive as local drive?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

Almost every remote desktop software has a file transfer mode where one can send/receive files between local and remote machine in their GUI, but I wonder which software can simply mount a remote drive as local drive so that I can use a file manager of my choice, not their GUI?

What I have considered so far:

1. RDP / Remote Desktop Connection: I know it can mount remote drive locally (albeit with an extra manual step of mapping a network drive locally), but it does not work from WAN without re-configuring the router port forwarding, which I can't do on the client's remote network.
2. Private VPN into the client's network and simply mapping their network drive once inside - can't set up VPN server on the client's remote network.

So I need something like RustDesk, but with ability to mount remote drives.

FOSS options are preferred.